# Why does rewrite not change the type of the expression in this case?

Tags: idris

In (*1) one can read next

> `rewrite prf in expr`
>
> If we have `prf : x = y`, and the required type for expr is some property of `x`, the `rewrite ... in` syntax will search for `x` in the required type of `expr` and replace it with `y`.

Now, I have next piece of code (you can copy it to editor and try ctrl-l)

```
module Test

plusCommZ : y = plus y 0
plusCommZ {y = Z} = Refl
plusCommZ {y = (S k)} = cong $ plusCommZ {y = k}

plusCommS : S (plus y k) = plus y (S k)
plusCommS {y = Z} = Refl
plusCommS {y = (S j)} {k} = let ih = plusCommS {y=j} {k=k} in cong ih

plusComm : (x, y : Nat) -> plus x y = plus y x
plusComm Z y = plusCommZ
plusComm (S k) y =
  let
    ih = plusComm k y
    prfXeqY = sym ih
    expr = plusCommS {k=k} {y=y}
    -- res = rewrite prfXeqY in expr
  in ?hole
```

below is how hole looks like

```
- + Test.hole [P]
 `--          k : Nat
              y : Nat
             ih : plus k y = plus y k
        prfXeqY : plus y k = plus k y
           expr : S (plus y k) = plus y (S k)
     -----------------------------------------
      Test.hole : S (plus k y) = plus y (S k)
```

**The Question.**
It looks to me like `expr` (from *1) in commented line equals to `S (plus y k) = plus y (S k)`. And `prf` equals to  `plus y k = plus k y` where `x` is `plus y k` and `y` is `plus k y`. And rewrite should search for `x` (namely for `plus y k`) in `expr` (namely `S (plus y k) = plus y (S k)` and should replace `x` with `y` (namely with `plus k y`). And result (`res`) should be `S (plus k y) = plus y (S k)`.

But this does not work.

I have next answer from idris

> rewriting plus y k to plus k y did not change type letty

I could guess rewrite is intended to change type of the resulting expression only. So, it is not working within body of `let` expression, but only in it's 'in' part. Is this correct?

(*1) http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/proofs/patterns.html

PS. Example from tutorial works fine. I'm just curious to know why the way I've tried to use rewrite didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though not stated explicitly stated in the docs, `rewrite` is syntax-sugary invocation of an `Elab` tactics script ([defined around here](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/f92ecd25d48a9120abfbb7d6af81f9b194ab98f1/src/Idris/Elab/Rewrite.hs)).

To why your example does not work: the "required type of `expr`" isn't found; with just `res = rewrite prfXeqY in expr` alone, it is unclear, which type `res` should have (even the unifier *could* resolve this with `let res = … in res`.) If you specify the required type, it works as expected:

```
res = the (S (plus k y) = plus y (S k)) (rewrite prfXeqY in expr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not provide the exact line which makes your code misbehave, somehow you must have done something strange, since with your reasoning you outlined above the code works well:

```
  let
    ih = plusComm k y -- plus k y = plus y k
    px = plusCommS {k=k} {y=y} -- S (plus y k) = plus y (S k)
    in rewrite ih in px
```

Comment: Markus, thank you for the answer. I have edited the post. Please see full code.

Comment: And, one more thing. It works inside `in` clause. It does not work if I write `res = rewrite prfXeqY in expr`.

Comment: I can imagine that rewrite does not behave as expected in let clauses as it is some kind of magic around `replace` and might get confused, but I have no source for this claim.

Comment: yes, I agree. I think it is because rewrite is what named "syntax sugar" and it does not behave like usual function (as I was expecting). If you would  put several sentenses of explanation to answer (so, people will see understandable anwser), I would accept it cause now I think nothing more is in this question. Thanks for helping me to understand.