# "rewriting did not change type" error for visually same types

Tags: functor, idris, theorem-proving

I wrote a short function:

```
swapMaybe : Monad m => Maybe (m a) -> m (Maybe a)
swapMaybe Nothing = pure Nothing
swapMaybe (Just x) = map Just x
```

Then I tried to prove one of its properties:

```
import Interfaces.Verified

swapMaybePreservesMap : VerifiedMonad m => (g : a -> b) -> (x : Maybe (m a)) ->
                        swapMaybe (map (map g) x) = map (map g) (swapMaybe x)
swapMaybePreservesMap g Nothing = ?hswapMaybePreservesMapNothing
swapMaybePreservesMap g (Just x) = ?hswapMaybePreservesMapJust
    (functorComposition x g Just)
    (functorComposition x Just (map g))
```

`:t hswapMaybePreservesMapJust` gives following type:

```
  a : Type
  b : Type
  g : a -> b
  m : Type -> Type
  x : m a
  constraint : VerifiedMonad m
--------------------------------------
hswapMaybePreservesMapJust : (map (\x1 => Just (g x1)) x = map Just (map g x)) ->
                             (map (\x1 => Just (g x1)) x = map (\meth => Prelude.Maybe implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map g meth) (map Just x)) ->
                             map Just (map g x) = map (\meth => Prelude.Maybe implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map g meth) (map Just x)
```

Visually the same left side `map (\x1 => Just (g x1)) x` of both parameters of `hswapMaybePreservesMapJust` looks promising for applying `rewrite`.

However, it fails:

```
swapMaybePreservesMap g (Just x) = rewrite (functorComposition x g Just) in 
    (functorComposition x Just (map g))
```

The error:

```
When checking right hand side of swapMaybePreservesMap with expected type
        swapMaybe (map (map g) (Just x)) = map (map g) (swapMaybe (Just x))

rewriting map (\x1 => Just (g x1)) x to map Just (map g x) did not change type map Just (map g x) =
                                                                               map (\meth => Prelude.Maybe implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map g meth) (map Just x)
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779105/why-rewrite-does-not-change-type-of-expression-in-this-case) and tried to explicitly specify the result type with `the`, moving `rewrite` parameters to `let` and eta-expand `map g`. Also without success, though:

```
swapEq : {x : a} -> {y : a} -> x = y -> y = x
swapEq eq = rewrite eq in Refl

swapMaybePreservesMap : VerifiedMonad n => (g : a -> b) -> (x : Maybe (n a)) ->
                        swapMaybe (map (\z => map g z) x) = map (\z => map g z) (swapMaybe x)
swapMaybePreservesMap g Nothing = ?hswapMaybePreservesMapNothing
swapMaybePreservesMap g xx@(Just x) = let
    pr1 = (swapEq $ functorComposition x g Just)
    pr2 = (functorComposition x Just (\z => map g z))
    in the (swapMaybe (map (\z => map g z) xx) = map (\z => map g z) (swapMaybe xx))
        (rewrite pr1 in pr2)
```

... with following message:

```
When checking right hand side of swapMaybePreservesMap with expected type
        swapMaybe (map (\z => map g z) (Just x)) = map (\z8 => map g z8) (swapMaybe (Just x))

When checking argument value to function Prelude.Basics.the:
        rewriting map Just (map g x) to map (\x1 => Just (g x1)) x did not change type map Just (map g x) =
                                                                                       map (\z11 => Prelude.Maybe implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map g z11) (map Just x)
```

As I've read in the [docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/proofs/patterns.html):

```
rewrite prf in expr
```

> If we have `prf : x = y`, and the required type for `expr` is some
>   property of x, the `rewrite ... in` syntax will search for `x` in the
>   required type of `expr` and replace it with `y`.

Why `rewrite` is not working in this case?

Is it because of actually different values at the left side of the parameters (maybe some implicit parameters are not shown) or somethhing else? Maybe it's better to apply some `Elab` tactics script explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason - it's different type constraints in `swapMaybe` and `swapMaybePreservesMap`. Following implementation gives a clear error:

```
swapMaybePreservesMap : VerifiedMonad m => (g : a -> b) -> (x : Maybe (m a)) ->
    swapMaybe (map (map g) x) = map (map g) (swapMaybe x)
swapMaybePreservesMap g Nothing = ?outOfScope
swapMaybePreservesMap g (Just x) = trans
    (sym $ functorComposition x g Just)
    (functorComposition x Just (map g))
```

The message:

```
When checking right hand side of swapMaybePreservesMap with expected type
        swapMaybe (map (map g) (Just x)) = map (map g) (swapMaybe (Just x))

When checking an application of function trans:
        Type mismatch between
                map (map g . Just) x = (map (map g) . map Just) x (Type of functorComposition x Just (map g))
        and
                map (\x1 => Just (g x1)) x = map (\meth => Prelude.Maybe implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map g meth) (map Just x) (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        map (map g) (map Just x)
                and
                        map (\meth => Prelude.Maybe implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map g meth) (map Just x)
```

Applying `VerifiedMonad` type constraint to `swapMaybe` instead of `Monad` makes type checker happy (with `swapMaybePreservesMap` implementation from above):

```
swapMaybe : Monad m => Maybe (m a) -> m (Maybe a)
swapMaybe Nothing = pure Nothing
swapMaybe (Just x) = map Just x
```

However, it'd be nice to prove some property of a function, working with some `Monad`, which holds only for `VerifiedMonad`.